# VSCode snippets - how to run a regex transform on the 'choice' result?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In this snippet defined in `keybindings.json` I'm trying to run a regex transform on the input result from [choice](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice) dialogue - I need the same value inserted twice, in 1st position I need the part before the first semicolon and in 2nd position I want the full choice value.

I tried examples from the doc but they don't seem to be working with the `choice`, or am I missing something? How do I achieve this?

```
{
    "key": "cmd+alt+ctrl+t",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "Before semicolon: ${2/(\\w);{1,}/$1/} & Full value: ${2|1; testValue1, 2; testValue2|}"
    }
},
```

expected output:

```
BeforeSemicolon: 1 & Full value: 1; testValue1
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation I have found a partial working.

It is important that the regex matches the full string. So add `.*` at the end.

(This should be added to the documentation)

```
{
    "key": "cmd+alt+ctrl+t",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "Before semicolon: ${1/([^;]*).*/$1/} && Full value: ${1|123; testValue1,223; testValue2|}"    }
},
```

And it only works for the first choice, **AND** you have to move the cursor inside the option text, just 1 <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> is enough, this accepts the choice but keeps the field active. And then <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Now the transform is applied.

You have to file a bug for this.

Comment: Not sure the vscode team would call the lack of choice transforms a "bug" but rather a "feature request".  Transforms have had a bit of an ugly history all in all, see, e.g., https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/51621 where in-place placeholder transforms were almost implemented and merged (presumably in-place choice transforms would have been straightforward after that work).  But work on those has stalled and the docs need to be rigorously worked on.

Answer (score 1):

Transform of choice variables is not supported.  There is a general discussion mentioning this at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/51621.

There are a couple of workarounds because transforms of placeholders do work as long as there is one non-transformed usage of the placeholder somewhere in the snippet.  Then a transformed version elsewhere will work.  This technique works for placeholder transforms but NOT choice transforms as you are trying to do.  Why that difference I don't know??

Simpler workaround 1 using one placeholder:

```
"snippet": "Before semicolon: ${1/([^;]*).*/$1/} && Full value: ${1:1; testValue1}"
```

Here you would have to accept the default placeholder value (`1; testValue1`) or overwrite it with another value.  Then on <kbd>tab</kbd> the transform will be applied to any other references to that same tabstop.

Complex workaround 2 usings multiple placeholders (in this case for 3 "choices":

```
"snippet": "Before semicolon: ${1/([^;]*).*/$1/}${2/([^;]*).*/$1/}${3/([^;]*).*/$1/} && Full value: ${1:1; testValue}${2:2; testValue}${3:3; testValue}"
```

Here you have to list your three (or however many you have) choices as separate placeholder tabstops.  Then you will either <kbd>tab</kbd> to accept that placeholder you want or <kbd>delete</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> those you don't.  It is a little tricky getting the delete/tab sequence down but once you have it, it is repetitve.  You see the cursor appears to be at the beginning of the next "choice" but it is really at the end of the previous "choice".

Here is a demo of version 2 where I choose each "choice"/placeholder in turn.  [I'm just using the  <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>  keybinding here to simplify.]

[image: "choice" transforms]

---

Obviously if potentially have a lot of "choices" you'll probably want to use version 1.  If you have a small number of "choices" that you want to be presented with and not have to type, version 2 does work pretty well.